# Loop for each subfolder R

Tags: r, loops

This is my code:

```
setwd("folder/subfolder1")
Data <- ReadAffy()
eset<-rma(Data)
write.expres(eset, file="subfolder1.txt")
```

I have a number of subfolders in my folder and and I want to make a script that will handle all of the subfolders in the loop and create text files named as subfolders.

How can I do this?

Comment: Loop through the vector of directory names returned by `list.dirs()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
# get into the parent directory
setwd("folder")
# loop through the sub directories (use [-1] to lop off the current directory: ".")
for (dir in list.dirs()[-1]) {
    # get into the sub directory
    setwd(dir)
    # do the do
    Data <- ReadAffy()
    eset<-rma(Data)
    # build the file name by pasting ".txt" on the end of the directory name
    write.expres(eset, file=paste(dir, "txt", sep="."))
    # pop back up to the parent directory
    setwd("../")
}
```